# Заполнение Combobox и проверка данных из БД MSSQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, combobox, ado

В БД имеется таблица с паролями. Делаю форму авторизации, кроме того мне нужны еще дополнительные поля выдернуть из этой таблицы и присвоить их значение переменным дальнейшей работы.
Сейчас если загрузка данных в Combobox происходит из БД то переменные остаются пустыми. Если же я в коллецию добавляю данные,
то все отлично работает все сохраняется.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Employees";
            dbTable = new DataTable();
            dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
            this.comboBox1.DataSource = dbTable;
            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "login";// столбец для отображения
            this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "empid";//столбец с id
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select login from Employees where login = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'and password= '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            dbTable = new DataTable();
            dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Office = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select kassir from Employees where login = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'and password= '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            kassir = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
            label1.Text = kassir;
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
```

Вот что хотелось бы в итоге.
Загрузить в combobox столбец с логинами при загрузке формы. При нажатии на кнопку проверить пароль. и вытащить значения login и kassir в соответствии с выбором в комбо. Еще раз повторюсь. Если создавать коллекцию комбо то все отлично работает. Все переменные передаются. А если при загрузке формы загружать из бд то при нажатии кнопки переменные пустые. подскажите что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подсказка: В аду есть отдельный котёл для разработчиков, хранящих пароли в БД в открытом виде.

Comment: плюс к предыдущему оратору: пароли в БД надо хранить с солью, а не в открытом виде.

Comment: у меня 5 нубских девочки(оператора) на работе. Эти пароли не для секретных программ. Просто дял авторизации в своем офисе. Даже если что стащут в данной программе ни чего страшного не произойдет

Comment: Я вам для чего писал в предыдущем вопросе об освобождении ресурсов, об sql-инъекции и параметрах, о правильном именовании? Чтобы вы всё это игнорировали? Тогда нет смысла вам отвечать.

Comment: `cmd.CommandText = "select login from Employees where login = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'and password= '" + textBox1.Text + "'";` Боже, так не пишут уже даже индусы. Проверочку того что ввел юзер не желаете сделать сначала? Вам нужно создать класс `Сотрудник` со свойствами соотв. столбцам таблицы, вытянуть из БД и создать коллекцию сотрудников и привязать ее источником к комбобоксу.

Comment: `Эти пароли не для секретных программ` да даже если это калькулятор с авторизацией для хранения истории вычислений, все равно даже вы как админ БД не должны знать паролей. Для этого существуют алгоритмы хеширования. А правильность пароля проверяется сравниванием хэшей. Ну и поищите "как правильно подставить параметры в SQL запрос C# ADO.NET". А то я вам введу в текстбокс с логином `x'; drop table Employees--`, и дело с концом. https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/base/level6/6_3.php

Comment: @Bulson именно так советуют проверять на Cyberforum. Я пока не профи. Только 3 месяца Ado учу. Так что не ругайтесь. а подскажите как правильно все параметры сравнить  или вытащить. Почему при загрузке из БД все пусто а если коллекцией то переменные заполняются в моей программе

Comment: @aepos у меня для логина combobox уже с фиксированным списком